# How do I select a particular string length starting from a specific sign(such as ':') in mysql?

Tags: mysql

For e.g. If I have column entry as 
'The only verdict is : Vendetta'

and the same column has another entry as 
'I believe in : Harvey Dent'

and all I want to select via my query is 'Vendetta' and 'Harvey Dent' i.e. the string just after the **:** sign, how do I do it? 
Can it be restricted to select upto a specific number of characters after the sign?

Comment: Are the first parts of the string a list of specific ones? Is the field limited so that is the only colon that can occur on it?

Answer (score 1):

If you only have one : in your string, you can give a look at [SUBSTRING_INDEX](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index):

```
SELECT
  col,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(col, ':', -1)
FROM
  tablename
```

or you can use SUBSTRING with [LOCATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_locate):

```
SELECT
  col,
  SUBSTRING(col FROM locate(':', col)+1)
FROM
  tablename
WHERE
  col LIKE '%:%'
```

(in your example you probably need to substitute ':' with ' : ' and +1 with +3)